# How to set JSON data in node.js response object?

Tags: node.js, jquery, express

I am using html on client side and my server side code is on node.js. I have some url's defined in to the nodejs application and I am calling them from my client html file. From node I am calling my REST application which is at another server. This rest application is written in Jersey java web services. I am able to call node.js from my html and from node code I am getting response from Jersey web service module. After receiving this response I am setting it to response object of node.js but this response is not available on html jquery ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type :"POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsontest,
    url: 'http://<code>localhost</code>:9999/hello',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.id);
    }, error : function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

Server side code:

```
var tmp = req;
var authentication = JSON.stringify(tmp.body.authenticationKey);

console.log("authentication :- "+authentication);

requestObj({
    url : "http://<code>restserver</code>:port/restmodule/controller/hello",
    method : "POST",
    headers : { "Content-Type" : "application/json","pubKey":authentication},
    body : JSON.stringify(tmp.body)
  },
  function (error, res, body) {
    indexresponseBody = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body).message);
  }
);

res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/html'});

console.log("JSON returned from REST "+indexresponseBody);

res.write(indexresponseBody);
res.end();
```

I am able to get the json and this is printed on node server console. But when I am writing this json to the response(res) object on firebug console I am not able to see this json. Can anybody tell me how can I get this response.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because of async nature of callback, try this -

```
function (error, resp, body) {
    indexresponseBody = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body).message);
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/html'});
    console.log("JSON returned from REST "+indexresponseBody);
    res.write(indexresponseBody);
    res.end();
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but still no response on client side response in firebug is blank

Comment: :-           POST http://10.1.15.131:9999/send 200 OK 17ms 
jquery-1.9.1.js (line 8526) {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}                 It shows statusText as "error" and status as 0 but on url it you see it is 200 OK. This is from firefox firebug.

Comment: try setting `content-type` to `application/json` in `writeHead`

Comment: I did in following way,<code> res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 res.header('Charset', 'utf-8');
 res.send(body);  
 res.end();
</code>. But this also does not worked for me.

Comment: Tried using writeHead to set content-type but that is also not working. I am not sure what is wrong.